# Rails Foundation Row style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I have followed the railscast for Zurb Foundation and I've set up a row with two divs:
    
      <%= yield %>

### sidebar

When I first load the page, unlike Ryan's example, the row seems to be centered (in the RailsCast example, everything is up against the left side of the screen).  when I examine the styling of the row, it has a margin-left: auto. If I turn this "off", everything shifts to the left as in the example.  Is there a place where this is set in foundation?  I downloaded the source code, and didn't see where the .row styling is specified.  I could add the styling to a secondary stylesheet, but I'd rather have it set in one place.

Answer (score 0):

modifying the value for
$row-width: rem-calc(2000);

seems to be getting the results I expected, though I'm still unclear on how rem-calc works...